# How to specify multiple principals in a policy document AWS CDK

Tags: typescript, amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, amazon-iam, aws-cdk

I am working on cdk script and I want to specify multiple principals such as

```json
"Principal": {
  "AWS": [
    "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-1", 
    "arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-2"
  ]
}
```

This is pretty straightforward in a JSON document but when writing with a policy document, I am unsure how to specify it.
I currently have

```js
const principals : Array<IPrincipal> = ['arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-1', 'arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-2'] 

const myPolicy = new PolicyDocument({
      statements: [
        new PolicyStatement({
          actions: ['*'],
          effect: Effect.ALLOW,
          principals: principals,
          resources: ['*'],
        }),
      ],
    });
```

How, this is erroring out as

`Cannot read property 'principalJson' of undefined`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `PolicyStatement` `principals` key accepts an array of `IPrincipal`, but you are giving it a string array.  The `IUser` type returned from the [User.fromUserArn](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.User.html#static-fromwbruserwbrarnscope-id-userarn) method is a superset of the `IPrincipal` interface, so that's what you need:

```js
const principals: Array<iam.IUser> = [
  'arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-1',
  'arn:aws:iam::AWS-account-ID:user/user-name-2',
].map((p, i) => iam.User.fromUserArn(this, `ImportedUser${i}`, p));
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Do you have a link to other superset methods of the IPrincipal interface? Wanted to also reuse this not only for users but also for root accounts as well.

Comment: @TensorLearn the [CDK docs page](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/v2/docs/aws-cdk-lib.aws_iam.IPrincipal.html) for IPrincipal lists the classes which implement the interface.